# WalletConnect V2 Getting No matching key. history: 1692426096597151 error in React+wagmi

Tags: reactjs, smartcontracts, wallet-connect

I there,

I'm trying to add WalletConnect V2 in my current running React JS project and I added React JS popup wallet connect modal and it's working fine fore connection my wallet using WalletConnect. And for the contract read and write I'm using @wagmi/core because I can made a global dynamic function it's working using @wagmi/core. It's work's for read and write function but when I wall write function which is using @wagmi/core at that time my popup modal opened as expected in meta mask but after click on Confirm Or Reject it gives me errors like No matching key. history: 1692426096597151 as attached in snapshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not post images of text when you can post the text itself